# SharePoint Server 2007 Quick Launch Order

Tags: sharepoint, frontpage, quicklaunch

Can I reorganize the Quick Launch without having FrontPage?

Answer (score 0):

About the best I can do is give you some links to articles about modifying SharePoint's Quick Launch. I don't use SharePoint ... at all.

[A quick post on how to modify the appearance of the QuickLaunch bar in SharePoint (WSS v3, SharePoint Server 2007)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150711191745/http://www.joiningdots.net:80/blog/2007/08/sharepoint-and-quick-launch.html)

[How to: Customize the Display of Quick Launch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms466994%28v=office.14%29)

[Customizing the Quick Launch menu: Adding fly-out menus to SharePoint navigation](https://web.archive.org/web/20101205012920/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2007/04/26/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-adding-fly-out-menus-to-sharepoint-navigation.aspx)

[Customize Quick Launch Menu](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10065698/customize-quick-launch-menu.aspx)

Apologies in advance if you've already seen all these.